# Is there a way to control which units initially appear in a battle in SW: Empire at War?

Tags: star-wars-empire-at-war

In land battles, you automatically start with one unit, which appears to be your strongest non-hero unit.
In space battles, enough units will initially spawn to fill your reinforcement cap.  Is there a way to control which units spawn?

For example, if I had some Y-wings but knew the enemy had a lot of Tartan frigates, I would like to be able to specify that the Y-wings should not spawn at the beginning of the battle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Empire at War.  In the Forces of Corruption expansion, however, fleets have a special slot which allow you to specify the unit which will spawn in first (and in land armies you can also specify which unit lands first).

Not only does this allow you to pick what ships are involved in a space battle, but you can warp in your cap ships close to the enemy starbase, which saves the travel time (as cap ships are so slow).